# Plotting a user-defined function with NMaximize

Tags: plotting, manipulate, mathematical-optimization

I am not sure what is going on with this plotting.

I see that the following code works:

```
TestFunction[a0_, a1_, a2_, x_] := a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2;

Manipulate[
 Plot[{TestFunction[a0, a1, a2, x], a0, a0 + a1*x}, {x, -10, 10}, 
  Evaluated -> True], {a0, -5, 5}, {a1, -5, 5}, {a2, -5, 5}]
```

However, suppose that my user-defined function involves NMaximize. I try to run the same thing with Evaluate -> True, but it does not work:

```
OptProfit[a0_, a1_, a2_, LB_, UB_] := 
  First[NMaximize[{a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2, LB <= x <= UB}, x]];

OptX[a0_, a1_, a2_, LB_, UB_] := 
  x /. Last[NMaximize[{a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2, LB <= x <= UB}, x]];

Manipulate[{
 Plot[OptProfit[a0, a1, a2, LB, UB], {LB, -10, UB}, 
  Evaluated -> True], 
Plot[OptX[a0, a1, a2, LB, UB], {LB, -10, UB}, 
  Evaluated -> True]}, {a0, -5, 5}, {a1, -5, 5}, {a2, -5, 5}, {UB, 0, 
  10}]
```

What's going on here? Why does it work in the TestFunction[] example but not when I use NMaximize[] when defining my user-defined function?

Follow-up question after Domen's answer. My actual function looks like:

```
ProfitRandomization[p_, \[Gamma]_, \[Delta]_, \[Alpha]_, 
  CMax_] := (First[
   NMaximize[{Boole[\[Eta]L <=  (\[Delta] \[Gamma] - 
           p)/\[Alpha] && \[Eta]L <= (-p (\[Alpha] + \[Gamma]) + (p + \
\[Alpha]) \[Gamma] \[Delta])/((\[Alpha] + \[Gamma]) (\[Alpha] + \
\[Gamma] \[Delta])) && (
          p - p \[Delta] + \[Alpha] \[Eta]L + \[Gamma] \[Delta] \
\[Eta]L)/(\[Alpha] \[Delta]) <= \[Eta]E <= (\[Gamma] - 
           p)/(\[Alpha] + \[Gamma]) && (
          p - p \[Delta] + \[Alpha] \[Eta]L)/(\[Alpha] \[Delta]) <=  \
\[Eta]E]*(p*(\[Eta]E + \[Eta]L)) +
      
      Boole[ \[Eta]L <= (-p (\[Alpha] + \[Gamma]) + (p + \[Alpha]) \
\[Gamma] \[Delta])/(\[Alpha] (\[Alpha] + \[Gamma] + \[Gamma] \
\[Delta])) && \[Eta]L <=  (\[Delta] \[Gamma] - 
           p)/\[Alpha] && \[Eta]E == (
          p - p \[Delta] + \[Alpha] \[Eta]L)/(\[Alpha] \
\[Delta])]*(p*(\[Eta]E + \[Eta]L)) +
      
      Boole[\[Eta]L <= (-p + \[Gamma] \[Delta])/(\[Alpha] + \[Gamma] \
\[Delta]) && \[Eta]E <= (
          p - p \[Delta] + \[Alpha] \[Eta]L)/(\[Alpha] \[Delta] + \
\[Gamma] \[Delta])]*p*(\[Eta]E + \[Eta]L),
     0 <= \[Eta]E <= CMax && 
      0 <= \[Eta]L <= CMax}, {\[Eta]E , \[Eta]L}]])

Manipulate[
 Plot[{ProfitRandomization[p, \[Gamma], \[Delta], \[Alpha], 
    CMax]}, {CMax, 0.01, 1},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, p}}], {\[Delta] , 
  0.01, .9999}, {\[Alpha], .01, 100}, {p, .01, 10}, {\[Gamma], 1, 
  10000}]

ProfitRandomization[2.62, 195.706, 0.317, 67.1, .488]
```

For some reason, the plot is not consistent with evaluating the function at a particular value. For example, if you set the parameters delta = 0.317, alpha = 67.1, p = 2.62, and gamma = 195.706, then looking at the plot at CMax = 0.488 does not give you the function evaluated at those values. Any guess as to what's going on here? This issue doesn't seem to appear with the simple quadratic function example, so I'm not sure what would cause this.

Comment: Remove ``Evaluated -> True`` and it [should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elA55.png). Furthermore, your maximization function doesn't seem very complicated, so you could also try using ``Maximize`` to get exact analytical solutions.

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I used NMaximize is because my actual function is more complicated than that. This was just a made-up minimally working example.